# Font Rendering Issue in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, typekit

One particular font in IBM PLEX: "Semibold" is not rendering properly on one particular indesign file. I'm using adobe cloud fonts.

There are no same fonts installed on the computer(so no competing).
I tried activating and deactivating the fonts from adobe fonts.
The font is rendering correctly on a new file. I tried clearing font-cache on my computer. I got this file from my colleague.

What might be the reason? Perplexed.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt file. Have you tried saving to an IDML file? That sometimes gets rid of weird, persistent font bugs.

Comment: Isn't it strange how there are different icons in the right side of the font drop down? Some have the "Activated font" icon and others have the "OpenType" icon.

Comment: It's a bad file.. or a font conflict.

Comment: This indeed looks like a font conflict. De-install it and see if InDesign still can find a copy.